# java servlet 3.0 null pointer forwarding jena query

Tags: jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception

i try to forward the data of jena query via servlet and beans to jsp.
when i try to iterate through the bean in the jsp.file, a NPE occurs. when i check against not null before iteration, jsp.file is showing up with no contents.

servlet

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Query query = QueryFactory.read(querySPARQL);
    // String co = request.getParameter("country");
    query = QueryFactory.create(query.toString().replaceAll("\\?country", "a:Netherlands"));

    QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(endpoint,
            query);

    try {
        ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
        PlantsBean bean = new PlantsBean(results);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("PlantsBean", bean);


    } finally {
        qexec.close();
    }
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

jsp.file

```
<%

        PlantsBean pb = (PlantsBean)session.getAttribute("PlantsBean");

        for(PowerPlantInfo ppi : pb) {
    %>
    <tr>


    <td><%=ppi.getFuel() %></td>


    </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
</table>
```

error message

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/SemTec1] threw exception   
[java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jsp.te_jsp._jspService(te_jsp.java:107)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

NPE occurs in line: for (PowerPlantInfo : ...). so the NPE says, that the bean is null. but that can not be possible. the jena query is working fine.
als i tried to put servlet in web-inf/classes, not working. yesterday, when i set up this whole thing once more, and the first time i ran it on server, it worked. 2nd time, not working anymore.

i'm using tomcat 7, jdk 7, and servlets 3.0.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your Servlet doesn't forward the request to the JSP. So I guess you're accessing the JSP directly (i.e., `http://yourhost/path/yourfile.jsp`).

Instead, I'd expect your Servlet redirects to the JSP (using `request.getRequestDispatcher("yourfile.jsp")`). When you visit your Servlet using your browser (i.e., `http://yourhost/path/YourServlet`), your Servlet will run, eventually redirecting to the JSP.